# Why Facebook Login Dialog not open if facebook app is installed on mobile

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am doing Facebook Integration using sdk 4.0.1, it works fine i got data from that but if you already have facebook app installed on your mobile then my Login Button of facebook doesn't work. It never show any Dialog box for login.
If i uninstall my Facebook app it appears and works correctly. why these issue occurs? Anyone has any solution for that??

Comment: When you press the button, it happens something? for example. The fb application show up though for a moment?

Comment: @RediOne1  So, what should i have to do for that?

Answer (score 0):

Just right this line

```
   LoginButton loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
   loginBtn.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

and for documentation read the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginBehavior/)..

SUPPRESS_SSO
Specifies that SSO should not be attempted, and to only use dialog auth.
public static final LoginBehavior SUPPRESS_SSO

Comment: please tell me how i declare "SessionLoginBehavior" ?

Comment: that is a static method...just write those two lines and you will abserve the difference....
had you entered this code in your class..?

Comment: Yes! but it ask me for SessionLoginBehavior, so how i declare it?

Comment: is your IDE shows any compile time error near SessionLoginBehaviour..?i guess?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

//Call this method on button click(take simple button)

```
  private void logInwithFacebook()
        {

            Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed())
            {
                Session session = new Session.Builder(LoginActivity.this).build();
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
                currentSession = session;
            }

            if (currentSession.isOpened())
            {
                // Do whatever u want. User has logged in

            }
            else

            if (!currentSession.isOpened())
            {
                // Ask for username and password
                OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest(LoginActivity.this);

                op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
                op.setCallback(new StatusCallback()
                {

                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
                    {

                        System.out.println("State= " + state);
                        if (session.isOpened())
                        {
                            System.out.println("Token=" + session.getAccessToken());
                            Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("USer :: "
                                            + user.toString());

                                    if (user != null)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("User=" + user);
                                    }
                                    if (response != null)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            System.out.println("USer ID :: "
                                                    + user.getId());
                                            System.out.println("USer FIrstname :: "
                                                    + user.getFirstName());
                                            System.out.println("USer Latname :: "
                                                    + user.getLastName());
                                            System.out.println("USer Birthdate :: "
                                                    + user.getBirthday());
                                            System.out.println("USer Gender :: "
                                                    + user.getInnerJSONObject().getString("gender"));
                                            System.out.println("USer Profile pic :: "
                                                    + "http://graph.facebook.com/"
                                                    + user.getId()
                                                    + "/picture"
                                                    + "?type=large");
                                            System.out.println("USer EmailAddress :: "
                                                    + user.asMap().get("email"));
                                            System.out.println("USer BIO :: "
                                                    + user.getInnerJSONObject().getString("bio"));






                                            //
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception e)
                                        {

                                        }
                                    }
                                    callFacebookLogout();

                                }

                            }).executeAsync();

                        }
                        if (exception != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Some thing bad happened!");
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
                permissions.add("user_birthday");
                permissions.add("email");
                permissions.add("public_profile");
                permissions.add("user_about_me");
                permissions.add("friends_birthday");

                op.setPermissions(permissions);

                Session session = new Session.Builder(LoginActivity.this).build();
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
                session.openForPublish(op);
            }

        }
```

//Logout from facebook

```
public void callFacebookLogout()
    {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null)
        {
            if (!session.isClosed())
            {
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            session = new Session(LoginActivity.this);
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }
    }
```

//onActivity Result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Facebook session
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```